# Can you identify this soldering station or its tips?

Tags: identification, soldering-iron-station

Some years ago I bought a store-branded soldering station (because it was cheap). I soon regretted my decision as the store only carried two kinds of spare tips: one conical and a huge chisel.

Recently the store stopped carrying the model and while they say that spare parts are available for at least 5 years, there will eventually be a time when I'm all outta tips.

So if you recognize the manufacturer or can recommend suitable tips based on the dimensions, that'd be awesome. I've tried a Hakko 900M tips and they're slightly too thin and fall off.

The station: http://www.clasohlson.com/fi/Juotosasema-Cotech/Pr408341000

The spare tips: [http://www.clasohlson.com/fi/Juotoskärjet-Cotech/40-8342](http://www.clasohlson.com/fi/Juotosk%C3%A4rjet-Cotech/40-8342)

The tip dimensions: outer diameter 6.4 mm (upper end) to 6.7 mm (lower end), inner diameter 4.6 mm, hole depth 24 mm, and finally the outside length 26 mm.

The heating element diameter is 4.5 mm.

Comment: Orphan soldering stations are a real environmental problem ! The fly by nighters that sell them should be held to task .

Comment: Couldn't agree more. The station build quality is actually pretty decent, so I'd hate to junk it just because of the tips.

Comment: This Skytronic / Mercury 703.050 station has similar design and similar performance, but there's just enough differences so it's not a simple copy. http://avslgroup.com/en/product/703.050UK

Comment: I thought that [these xytronic LF-369D(Hakko-style) tips](http://www.partco.biz/verkkokauppa/index.php?cPath=2072_1169_1220) might be a match, but apparently they aren't; They have a 4mm inner diameter. I did find [these 25 W tips on ebay](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Replacement-Antex-Soldering-Iron-Tips-various-sizes-for-18w-25w-irons-/151951396817), where they state "All tips are a push fit onto a 4.5mm dia element.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I peeked at the bottom of the thing, and there it was, "Model: JS1104HT".

Looking that up gets a few hits, mostly in Alibaba, advertising the very same thing in various colors. Or even blue, as it happens:

http://www.primusdanmark.dk/loddestation-digital-temperatur-p-2399.html

Original manufacturer is Jinshun Tools who apparently even have a website and one of these days it might even load.

Thanks to everyone for your tip hints, I'll be trying some of them out depending on local availability.

EDIT: The tips for Skytronic / Mercury 703.050 model appear to fit just fine. They're a lot longer than the originals, but the barrel end is where it counts.

(Disclaimer: I haven't tried soldering with the new tips yet)

Answer (score 1):

Looks very similar to the Weller ETP tip. Weller is a high quality brand so if your unit is a rip off, there's a good chance it'll be a good fit. Here's a [Digi-Key link](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/ETP/ETP-ND/251747) for one.

Comment: I think we have a Weller that uses those tips back in the office; I'll have a look the next time I'm around. But my initial recollection is that those would be shorter so might not be a good fit.

Comment: That's one of the shorter ones that Weller has. I personally have a couple different sized tips for my Weller that I swap in and out depending on the job I'm doing. The main thing you need to check is whether or not it works in your wand or not. If it does, then any Weller tip made for that class of wand should work for you.